# TeamCity cross-browser Webdriver multiple test failure information

Tags: nunit, selenium-webdriver, teamcity

I have a suite of Webdriver tests in NUnit that I have running repeatedly on a TeamCity server. I'm getting the driver type from a config file that is altered between test runs; this was the most elegant way of doing cross-browser testing within NUnit that I could come up with. Fortunately, TeamCity combines the output of all the test runs quite neatly. Unfortunately, when a test fails more than once, only one failure and its accompanying stack trace is displayed, with an annotation of "2 failures in one build." Since these are actually different tests, being in different browsers, I would like to view the error outputs separately. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For cross browser testing you can consider using [Grid 2](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) instead of changing the browser type from the configuration file.

In addition you'll be able to run in your tests in parallel on different browsers
**and solve your multiple test failure information**